# how to check if a key equal a value in swift dictionary?

Tags: swift

let say I have this dictionary

```
var myDic = ["Item" : " Item1", "Item2" : " Item3"]
```

how can I write an if statement to check if Item and Item1 are a key-value paire?

Comment: You check what has been discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63651812/how-can-i-check-if-a-key-and-a-value-are-linked-in-a-dictionary-in-swift)

Comment: @thx but I don't see the answer

Comment: If someone has the answer it will be much appreciated. I don't see the answer in the page pointed by @Joakim Danielson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

> Every dictionary is an unordered collection of key-value pairs. You
> can iterate over a dictionary using a for-in loop, decomposing each
> key-value pair into the elements of a tuple.

This means you can write the following code:

```
let myDict = ["Item" : " Item1", "Item2" : " Item3"]
for (key, val) in myDict {
    if (key == "Item2" && val == " Item3") {
        print("match!") //prints match!
    }
}
```

This is obviously kind of a "naive" approach where the values are hardcoded in the *if-statement*. A one-line alternative:

```
print(myDict.contains(where: { $0.key == "Item2" && $0.value == " Item3" })) //true
```

Let's say you need to check for two pairs. Then you can use *KeyValuePairs* which preserves the order and simply iterate:

```
let toFind: KeyValuePairs = [ "Item2" : " Item3",  "Itemx" : " Item4"]
for tup in toFind {
    print(myDict.contains(where: { $0 == tup })) //true, false
}
```

If you want to follow this approach, I recommend reading about the important differences between Dictionary and KeyValuePairs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs